# External Navigation for navigating inside an iFrame

Tags: html, iframe, navigation, external

After all the time of staying away from things like iframes, it finally caught back on me. A client wants a part of his Shop showing on his website, via iFrame.

But lets just skip right to the problem:

There is the main html site, which holds the iframe displaying the shop.
Above that iframe, there is a submenu, which is supposed to open links INSIDE the iframe.

The problem is, that I don't have any clue how to do that. Is there a way of using anchors to switch / navigate sites inside an iframe?

Thanks in advance, I hope you guys can help me with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give the `iframe` a `name` attribute (e.g. `name="shopContent"`).  You can then make links access the `iframe` using the `target` attribute on your link element:

```
<a href="bananas.htm" target="shopContent">Bananas</a>
```

Comment: Gosh, who could have thought it would be that easy! Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, that totally did it. Just one more thing: does this work with every (modern) browser (Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera, IE7-9)?